# Save function is not working in expressjs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to save form data into mongodb database. when I try to use .Find method it returns data from users collection. But it shows an error message when I try to save data. .Save method should also work with the same Schema but it is not.Here is my code:

```
var express= require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');    
var app= express();
/* set view folder and view engine */
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());    
/* database connection */
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/expresstest', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }   
});

/* define user schema */
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({name:String, password: String, phone: String, created: Date});
var User= mongoose.model('users',UserSchema);
/* open new user form */
app.get('/user', function(req, res){
    res.render('user');
});

/* save user */
app.post('/user', function(req, res){
    User.save({
        name: req.body.name, 
        password: req.body.password, 
        phone: req.body.phone
    }, function( error, docs) {
        res.redirect('/')
    });
});    
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('express app is running on port 3000.');
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the error message?

Comment: TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
   if (!(this instanceof model)) {
     return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
   }
   Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
 } has no method 'save'
   at app.post.articleProvider.save.title (/var/www/html/express/app.js:47:7)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/var/www/html/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)

Comment: Try changing `save` to `create`.

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyHK now it is working. what was the problem with save()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are calling the functions wrong. Here are the function signatures. Save is called on an object of `User` while create is called on the model `User` itself. Here is an example:

```
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);

var small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
small.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});

// or

Tank.create({ size: 'small' }, function (err, small) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

Read more about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Comment: How can we push an object into an existing array field using `save` method?